# spring: how to transform java security config to yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I try to translate the following websecurity configuration written in Java to a plain-yml configuration.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

This is the security relevant part of my application.yml:

```
security:
  require_ssl: true
  basic:
    enabled: true
  enable_csrf: false
  ignored:
    - /register/**
```

When I use the yml-version the endpoints are not accessible without authentication, but also valid users are not permitted to access the site. I think it's because I am using a custom `userDetailsService` which is not recognised.

How can I define the same behaviour of the `registerAuthentication`-method part with the yml-version? Is there a security.userDetailsServiceClass property or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

On [application properties reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) there is nothing related to `UserDetailsService`, so must be not supported,also it's a advanced condiguration which can be done by normal configuration. Boot provides via properties only simple configuration to get start quickly, like `httpBasic`, you can combine both, but note your

```
ignored:
    - /register/**
```

are clashing with Java Config's matchers